# JavaScript Data Binding Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding

I'm looking for something like Flex's ArrayCollection and ArrayList; a lightweight wrapper around JavaScript's Array that supports data binding to do something (ie. call a function) on data change.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at jQXB Expression Binder. It does exacly what you need, binding capabilities, templating and messaging. http://www.jqxb.altervista.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that javascript has any similar functionality. I believe the best solution would be a function that adds or updates an array and runs other functions from within that like rerender the list or page.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js [Collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) is a very popular implementation of this. Many of the libraries covered in [TodoMVC](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/) also have something like evented collections. Unfortunately they do more than just this one thing.